# Suppressing touch points in Silverlight WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, multi-touch

I'm writing a hybrid XNA + Silverlight app for WP7 and I'm trying to work out the touch splitting between them. I've got this halfway worked out: I can suppress XNA `TouchPanel` touches when the user clicks a Silverlight button. However I have not figured out how to throw out game-only touches for Silverlight. So if you're holding a touch point in the game space (say, for moving the player around), a second touch on a button won't work. It think it's picking it up as a multi-touch gesture and only allowing the first touch point to click buttons.

My question is: how can you suppress this touch point in Silverlight processing?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way woudl be to design your app so that you don't use both types of control in an interactive way on the same page.

Or, if you must, when you detect the first XNA touch disable touch on the Silverlight controls.

Comment: Well yeah, of course this would work if I just threw one of them out the window! But the question is about getting the hybrid approach to work. Disabling Silverlight touch on the first XNA touch would not help me because I want them to be treated as a single touch on each.